# Check the total counts of gallery items and compare it to form field values

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

I have this screen which contain 2 components:-

1. Form with 3 fields (Art Description + Number of Art + Quantity)
2. Gallery with 2 fields (Sub Quantity + Sub Quantity For each Artwork)

[image]

now when clicking on the Submit button, I am submitting the Form + Patch the gallery fields.. but I want to do these validations before doing the submissions: -

1. The "Sub Quantity For Each art" , must contain comma separated numbers count = "Number of Art" field value inside the form.
2. The sum inside the "Sub Quantity for Each art" (the numbers between the commas), must equal the "Sub Quantity" field value inside the gallery.

So can anyone advice on the formulas i need to add?

Thanks